# Error when parsing buffer to create a tuple

Tags: c++11, buffer, tuples

I am trying to build a tuple by reading from a buffer. Here is my code:

```
template<class T>
T read_from_stream(char *& stream)
{
    T value;
    memcpy(&value, stream, sizeof(T));
    stream += sizeof(T);
    return value;
}


template <typename ... Args>
tuple<Args...> parse(char * buffer)
{
    return tuple<Args...>{read_from_stream<Args>(buffer)...};
}
```

and I use it like

```
auto tup = parse<float, int, char>(buf);
```

Now suppose the added data in buffer is in sequence float, int, char... the read_from_stream gets called in the reverse order i.e for char first then for int and then for float. I am having to specify the function template parameter types in the reverse order (parse) to read the data correctly. I want the order to be preserved.
What am I doing wrong?

I am using vs2013(update 4) by the way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bug in your compiler, actually. The standard mandates that during list initialisation, elements of an initialiser list be evaluated strictly in the order they appear. Quoting C++11 8.5.4/4:

> Within the *initializer-list* of a *braced-init-list,* the *initializer-clauses,* **including any that result from pack
>   expansions** (14.5.3), are evaluated in the order in which they appear. That is, every value computation and
>   side effect associated with a given *initializer-clause* is sequenced before every value computation and side
>   effect associated with any *initializer-clause* that follows it in the comma-separated list of the *initializer-list.*
>   [ *Note:* This evaluation ordering holds regardless of the semantics of the initialization; for example, it applies
>   when the elements of the *initializer-list* are interpreted as arguments of a constructor call, even though
>   ordinarily there are no sequencing constraints on the arguments of a call. *—end note* ]

(Emphasis mine)

And indeed, using GCC, your code [works just fine](http://tinyurl.com/pnjsdga).